# How to take 2 avg() from mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT AVG(`tmp`) FROM `monitor` WHERE `id`='7' ORDER BY `counter` DESC LIMIT 75
SELECT AVG(`tmp`) FROM `monitor` WHERE `id`='4' ORDER BY `counter` DESC LIMIT 75
```

I want to see 2 avg easy to compare in my phpmyadmin. Singe line above will work but i can't combine them :/

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation if you want the results in two columns:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN id = 7 THEN tmp END) as avg_7,
       AVG(CASE WHEN id = 4 THEN tmp END) as avg_4
FROM monitor
WHERE id IN (4, 7);
```

The `ORDER BY` and LIMIT` are non-sensical in your question because the queries return only one row.

If you prefer two rows, then you have several choices.  I think I would go with aggregation:

```
SELECT id, AVG(tmp) as average
FROM monitor
WHERE id IN (4, 7)
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT AVG(`tmp`) FROM `monitor` WHERE `id`='7' ORDER BY `counter` DESC LIMIT 75
UNION
SELECT AVG(`tmp`) FROM `monitor` WHERE `id`='4' ORDER BY `counter` DESC LIMIT 75;
```

Comment: I've tried Union, and I don't know whether second would work but i want 2 averages in my result, 2 records on output with 2 avrages

Comment: Yes, the second query should be rewritten with a `GROUP BY` clause and the id should be added to the `SELECT` parameters. I removed it, since it's already done in the other answer.

Comment: I noticed that `UNION` makes a union in the "set" sense. So if the 2 resulting rows are equivalent (e.g. they are both `22.71892`) only one row will be shown. Both rows will be shown If the values are different. Keep that in mind.

Comment: In conclusion, I'd say that the best solution is the one with the `GROUP BY` clause :)